# Get keys from template

Tags: python, string-formatting

I would like to get a list of all possible keyword arguments a string template might use in a substitution.

**Is there a way to do this other than re?**

I want to do something like this:

```
text="$one is a $lonely $number."
keys = get_keys(text) 
# keys = ('one', 'lonely', 'number')
```

I'm writing a simple Mad-lib-like program, and I want to perform template substitution with either [string.format](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) or [Template strings](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#template-strings). I'd like to write the 'story' and have my program produce a template file of all the 'keywords' (nouns, verbs, etc.) that a user would need to produce. I know I can do this with regular expressions, but I was wondering if there is an alternative solution? I'm open to alternatives to string.format and string template.

I thought there would be solution to this, but I haven't come across it in a quick search. I did find this question, [reverse template with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001537/reverse-template-with-python), but it's not really what I'm looking for. It just reaffirms that this can be done with `re`.

**EDIT:**

I should note that `$$` is an escape for '$', and is not a token I want. `$$5` should render to "$5".

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If it's okay to use `string.format`, consider using built-in class `string.Formatter` which has a `parse()` method:

```
>>> from string import Formatter
>>> [i[1] for i in Formatter().parse('Hello {1} {foo}')  if i[1] is not None]
['1', 'foo']
```

See [here](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.Formatter.parse) for more details.

Comment: Pretty much what I was looking for. Maybe my question needs work but I  basically didn't want to reinvent the wheel. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't work if the string starts with a key. Try the above with `{foo} test`

Comment: @syntacticmarmalade Works fine for me on Python 3.6. If you mean that the list has a `None` at the end, that's because the string does not *end* with a key. You can just filter the instances of `None` out.

Answer (score 12):

The `string.Template` class has the pattern that is uses as an attribute. You can print the pattern to get the matching groups

```
>>> print string.Template.pattern.pattern

    \$(?:
      (?P<escaped>\$) |   # Escape sequence of two delimiters
      (?P<named>[_a-z][_a-z0-9]*)      |   # delimiter and a Python identifier
      {(?P<braced>[_a-z][_a-z0-9]*)}   |   # delimiter and a braced identifier
      (?P<invalid>)              # Other ill-formed delimiter exprs
    )
```

And for your example,

```
>>> string.Template.pattern.findall("$one is a $lonely $number.")
[('', 'one', '', ''), ('', 'lonely', '', ''), ('', 'number', '', '')]
```

As you can see above, if you do `${one}` with braces it will go to the third place of the resulting tuple:

```
>>> string.Template.pattern.findall('${one} is a $lonely $number.')
[('', '', 'one', ''), ('', 'lonely', '', ''), ('', 'number', '', '')]
```

So if you want to get all the keys, you'll have to do something like:

```
>>> [s[1] or s[2] for s in string.Template.pattern.findall('${one} is a $lonely $number.$$') if s[1] or s[2]]
['one', 'lonely', 'number']
```

Answer (score 4):

You could render it once with an instrumented dictionary which records calls, or a defaultdict, and then check what it asked for.

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict("bogus")
text%d
keys = d.keys()
```

Answer (score 1):

try `str.strip()` along with `str.split()`:

```
In [54]: import string

In [55]: text="$one is a $lonely $number."

In [56]: [x.strip(string.punctuation) for x in text.split() if x.startswith("$")]
Out[56]: ['one', 'lonely', 'number']
```

Comment: **$** is part of **string.punctuation**, making **lstrip('$')** redundant

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to avoid regular expressions? They work quite well for this:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\$[a-z]+', "$one is a $lonely $number.")
['$one', '$lonely', '$number']
```

For templating, check out [re.sub](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub), it can be called with callback to do almost the thing you want.

Comment: I don't want to avoid regular expressions, I was just wondering if there was another way.

Comment: Well, if you want an african animal with a long neck, it's certainly possible to stretch a crocodile, but in most cases it's easier to go with a giraffe.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
def get_keys(s):
    tokens = filter(lambda x: x[0] == "$", s.split())
    return map(lambda x: x[1:], tokens)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import string
>>> get_keys = lambda s:[el.strip(string.punctuation) 
                         for el in s.split()if el.startswith('$')]
>>> get_keys("$one is a $lonely $number.")
['one', 'lonely', 'number']
```