# Extracting keys from %-style format string template

Tags: python

I have a string using the `%` style formatting that I would like to extract its keys from:

```
s = 'Hello %(name)s, you are %(age)d years old!'
```

I would like to do something such as:

```
from string import Formatter
keys = {key for _, k, _, _ in Formatter().parse(s)}
print(keys)
# ('name', 'age')
```

However, this is unsupported with `%` style formatting; is there another way? I've also already read:

1. [How can I extract keywords from a Python format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25996937/how-can-i-extract-keywords-from-a-python-format-string)
2. [Get keys from template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13037401/get-keys-from-template)

Comment: `re.findall(r'%\((\w+)\)', s)` works on the given example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well `re.findall` can easily get the keys:

```py
s = 'Hello %(name)s, you are %(age)d years old!'
keys = re.findall(r'%\((.*?)\)', s)
print(keys)  # ['name', 'age']
```

I'm not sure exactly what you want to do with these keys though.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun but not recommended for production use:

```py
>>> s = 'Hello %(name)s, you are %(age)d years old!'
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(float)
>>> s % d
'Hello 0.0, you are 0 years old!'
>>> d.keys()
>>> for k in d:
...     print(k)
...
name
age
>>>
```