# Reversing C-style format strings in Python (`%`)

Tags: python, string, c-strings

## Introduction and setup

Suppose I have a 'template'* string of the form,

```
>>> template = """My %(pet)s ate my %(object)s.
... This is a float: %(number)0.2f.
... %(integer)10d is an integer on a newline."""
```

With this template I can generate a new string with,

```
>>> d = dict(pet='dog', object='homework', number=7.7375487, integer=743898,)

>>> out_string = template % d

>>> print(out_string)
My dog ate my homework.
This is a float: 7.74.
    743898 is an integer on a newline.
```

How nice!

## Question

I'd like to apply `template` to `out_string` to produce a new `dict`. Something like,

```
>>> d_approx_copy = reverse_cstyle_template(out_string, template)
>>> print(d_approx_copy)
{pet='dog', object='homework', number=7.74, integer=743898,}
```

Is there a Pythonic way to do this? Does an implementation already exist?**

#### Notes

*: I'm not using [Template](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#template-strings) because, AFAIK, they don't currently support *reversing*.

**: I am aware of the *risks* associated with the loss of precision in `number` (from `7.7375487` to `7.74`). I can deal with that.  I'm just looking for a simple way to do this.

Comment: i think there is no need for regex tag..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I was developing this question, I could not find an existing tool to reverse C-style strings this way.  That is, I think the answer to this question is: the `reverse_cstyle_template` function I was looking for does not currently exist.

In the process of researching this topic, I found many questions/answers similar to this one that use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) (e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001537/reverse-template-with-python), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844986/convert-string-to-variables-like-format-but-in-reverse-in-python), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362788/reverse-of-python-string-formatting-generating-a-dict-from-a-string-with-named)). However, I wanted something simpler and I did not want to have to use a different template string for formatting vs. parsing.

This eventually led me to [format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax), and [Richard Jones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/288169/richard-jones)' [parse](https://github.com/r1chardj0n3s/parse) package. For example the template above is written in format string syntax as,

```
>>> template = """My {pet} ate my {object}.
... This is a float: {number:0.2f}.
... {integer:10d} is an integer on a newline."""
```

With this template, one can use the built-in `str.format` to create a new string based on `d`,

```
template.format(**d)
```

Then use the [parse](https://github.com/r1chardj0n3s/parse) package to get `d_approx_copy`,

```
>>> from parse import parse
>>> d_approx_copy = parse(template, out_string).named
```

Note here that I've accessed the `.named` attribute. This is because `parse` returns a `Result` object (defined in parse) that captures both *named* and *fixed* format specifiers. For example if one uses,

```
>>> template = """My {pet} {}ate my {object}.
... This is a float: {number:0.2f}.
... {integer:10d} is an integer on a newline.
... Here is another 'fixed' input: {}"""

>>> out_string = template.format('spot ', 7, **d)

>>> print(out_string)
My dog spot ate my homework.
This is a float: 7.74.
    743898 is an integer on a newline.
Here is another 'fixed' input: 7
```

Then we can get the fixed and named data back by,

```
>>> data = parse.parse(template, out_string)

>>> print(data.named)
{'pet': 'dog', 'integer': 743898, 'object': 'homework', 'number': 7.74}

>>> print(data.fixed)
('spot ', '7')
```

Cool, right?!

Hopefully someday this functionality will be included as a built-in either in `str`, or in [Template](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#template-strings). For now though [parse](https://github.com/r1chardj0n3s/parse) works well for my purposes.

Lastly, I think it's important to re-emphasize the **loss of precision** that occurs through these steps when specifying precision in the format specifier (i.e. `7.7375487` becomes `7.74`)! In general using the precision specifier is probably a bad idea except when creating 'readable' strings (e.g. for 'summary' file output) that are not meant for further processing (i.e. will never be *parsed*). This, of course, negates the point of this Q/A but needs to be mentioned here.