# Find keyword arguments from a c-style python string and text

Tags: python-2.7

How can I find the keyword argument passed to a `c-style` python string

Given:

```
bill eats apple
'%(name)s eats %(fruit)s'
```

Should get

```
{ 'name': 'bill', 'fruit' : 'apple'}
```

Comment: You may want to give [the `parse` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/parse) a try.

Comment: ok, so nothing direct?, I would have to use `re` and stuff only.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you mean you want to try to only use modules that ship with Python? If so, why? Would you consider it acceptable to copy/paste the code from the `parse` module? (If not, why not? If so, why wouldn't you just use the module?)

Comment: I am very happy with the module you suggested, as first it seemed a simple task to me, so I thought is that really that hard, can't I come up with a line or two of code myself. As i understand, it's not that simple/direct, given strings can grow complex.

Comment: not able to do it with parse module also,  only seems to be working with `{}` type parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to use `parse`, you can convert your pattern string to a regular expression using [named groups](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups) and then use `re.match` and `match.groupdict` to get the mapping.

```
>>> text = "bill eats apple"
>>> a = "%(name)s eats %(fruit)s"
>>> p = re.sub(r"%\((\w+)\)s", r"(?P<\1>\w+)", a)
>>> p
'(?P<name>\\w+) eats (?P<fruit>\\w+)'
>>> re.match(p, text).groupdict()
{'fruit': 'apple', 'name': 'bill'}
```

Note that `\w+` will only match a single word. To allow for more complex names, you might instead use e.g. `[^(]+` to match anything up to the closing `)`

```
>>> text = "billy bob bobbins eats a juicy apple"
>>> p = re.sub(r"%\((\w+)\)s", r"(?P<\1>[^)]+)", a)
>>> re.match(p, text).groupdict()
{'fruit': 'a juicy apple', 'name': 'billy bob bobbins'}
```

Comment: this doens't work when  `name` has a space in between.

Comment: @garg10may That's right, in this case you will have to replace `\w+` with something more complex, maybe `[^)]+` or similar.

Comment: that gives `sre_constants.error: unbalanced parenthesis`

Comment: thx, not sure how it works but your `re` works magic. Using parse would have required changing everything given I was using django translations it would be more cubersome. And replacing `%' prior to using parse would also not be possible since now the translations won't work.

Answer (score 1):

First, there is no function or package in Python that allow you to do that with *old style* (aka *C style*) string formatting. [A good reference about reversing c-style string format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26411056/reversing-c-style-format-strings-in-python).

The best you can have is a giant regex pattern and as you know it's really not a perfect solution.

---

That said,

As [@smarx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/94559/smarx) said in comments, you can use [`parse`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/parse) which is well fitted for that, but, from the given doc's link:

> parse() is the opposite of format()

That mean you needs to use `format()` instead of `%`, which is a good thing because `%` is Python's string formatting *old style* where [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#format) is the *new style* and the best to use since Python3 (it's python 2.7 / 3 compliant, but not `%`).

Here is an example with [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#format):

```
print(parse.parse('{name} eats {fruit}', 'bill eats apple'))
<Result () {'fruit': 'apple', 'name': 'bill'}>
```

If you are not confortable with `format()` I advise you to give a look at [pyformat.org](https://pyformat.info/), a really good guide.

Comment: but my strings don't use format, would mean changing existing texts.

Comment: I updated my answer, from what I saw you have two solutions: 1. Use `format()` or use homemade regex pattern and hope it will works in most of case. Again, even if that needs to change texts I advise you to use `format()`

Comment: @garg10may Can't you just `replace` `%(` with `{` and `)s` with `}` prior to using `parse`?